# Try to execute command line codes from c++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, command-prompt

I tried the following code, to communicate with the command line from c++ code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cv.h>

int main()
{
    system("gnome-terminal");
    system("cd");
}
```

The gnome-terminal command is executing fine. After I close the terminal, when am expecting the cd to execute, however, is not happening. Could you please help me and point out the reason? Thanks. I was expecting the function to make the cmd go down to the home directory
, but it did not. am working in linux

I tried it even by removing gnome. simple cd is not working. am I doing something rong>?

If I try ls, it seems to be working fine!

My main aim is to open a new terminal, and execute commands on that new terminal through the present program that opened the new terminal. Could you please tell me how I can achieve this??

Comment: What is "cv.h". And you don't (visibly) include the right header for system. You need <cstdlib> (then it is called std::system()) or <stdlib.h> (then it is system).

Comment: am developing the code. this is the starting phase. Thanks for your tipw :). Will correct it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the working directory of the shell from which you execute the C++ program?

Comment: yes. I was trying that. Now I thought am trying to execute commands in the new terminal opened, from the c++ program opened in the different shell! could you help me here? please see the edit.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/198015/open-gnome-terminal-programmatically-and-execute-commands-after-bashrc-was-execu

I think this is wat am looking for. But am not able to understand the answer. Could you pls verify if am on the right track @aschepler

Comment: The `-e` option to `gnome-terminal` will let you make the terminal execute another command right away, if that's what you want.

Comment: am not talking about the -e option bro. am saying about this one

gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'command1; command2; exec bash'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to run a program and wait for it to finish before executing next line, take a look at this page and example code here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/c-process-control-functions/

But if you want to run gnome-terminal and execute a command in newly created window, do this:

```
system("gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'cd /tmp ; ls -la'");
```

Comment: sorry bro. this is not wat am looking for. am sry if I wasn't clear in my question. pls see the edit.

Comment: The `system` function is equivalent to doing `fork`, `exec`, and `waitpid`, but easier.  (For when you don't want to do any redirects, pipes, etc.)

Comment: should I use escape characters for the quote?? I feel something is slightly missing.

Comment: Yes, you can use single quota also

Answer (score 7):

The `system` function creates a shell child process to execute the specified command.

`cd` is a shell command which changes the current working directory of that shell process only.

So the child's `cd` probably works fine, but it has no effect on your C++ program, which is a different process.

Instead, you probably want to look at the Linux system call [`chdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir).

Comment: he want to see next command executed after gnome-terminal being terminated, not right after.

Comment: Although `chdir` will change the CWD for your process, not its parent (the shell).  Sounds like what the OP really wants is a shell script.

Comment: If you want to execute something WITHIN the gnome-terminal, you will need to do something different than the code you've just posted. There are multiple ways you could achieve something like what you are asking for - you could generate a shell-script file, and execute that, or you could open a pipe and send commands through that - or even open a pseudo-terminal and use the "master" side of that pseudoterminal to "write" to the actual terminal.

Comment: Even `chdir()` probably wouldn't have the desired effect, as it would only change the working directory for the C program, not for the parent shell. Shell function maybe?

Comment: Yes, chdir() did not work for me. I am a beginner and am not able to understand many of your comments. I am really sorry, but ould you please explain wat I can do??

Comment: I hate it when I solve the problem with my answer, do not receive a respect from positive votes, another answer receives and even asker doesn't respect the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!! This command worked perfectly fine from this link

https://superuser.com/questions/198015/open-gnome-terminal-programmatically-and-execute-commands-after-bashrc-was-execu

```
    gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'command1; command2; exec bash'
```

and I entered the respective commands in the new window. But to change the working directory in the shell am working o, I haven't still figured that out.

Comment: like what I gave in above comment/answer, huh?

Comment: yeah. actually, I was seeing another link,and only after I got back, saw ur answer, and thus verified this has to b the answer. But that link also said about including this exec bash command and other stuff, which was informatory, thus wanted to highlight here.

Comment: so my answer helped you and my answer is exactly what you are looking for, so you can accept the proper answer and close the question

Comment: Oh, sorry. Was looking for some other code, and I thot I had marked it as the answer.

Comment: @Vahid Farahmand, your answer doesn't end in `exec bash`, as his does. That can make a huge difference. `exec bash` keeps the terminal open when done. I have to use it in my answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application/1026563#1026563 (`exec $SHELL` works too) and here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal/1209836#1209836.