# How to make a console application close automatically after command in C++?

Tags: c++

I would like to know How to make a console application close automatically after command in C++?

I want my program to ask "1) continue 2) Exit" and obviously proceed with the selected choice.

This is what I got so far:

```cpp
 #include <iostream>
 
 int main() {
     int choice;
  
     std::cout << "1) continue 2) Exit. \n\n";
     std::cout << std::endl;
     std::cin  >> choice;
     std::cout << std::endl;
 
     if (choice == 1) { 
         std::cout << " choice 1 selected, let's continue!";   
    }
    
    if (choice != 1) {
        //then close automatically?
    }
 }
```

Comment: You are probably talking about Visual Studio console app. Note that your program does not own the console. It can be run from commandline window. If you are running it from Visual Studio, whether it closes at the end of the program depends on running with or without debugging.

Comment: `exit(0)` on second choice. `exit` is a function in standard library. try it out.

Comment: @Eugene, Nowadays, the VS console will actually pause at the end and give you a helpful message explaining how to disable that behaviour if you so choose.

Comment: @abdullahQureshee exit(0) will not close console. Cannot do it programmatically from a "console app".

Comment: @Eugene agreed. exit(0) ends(exits) the program only.

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532496/try-to-execute-command-line-codes-from-c-linux) ?

Comment: Closing a console app is not the same thing as closing the console in which the console app runs. Did you mean the latter when you wrote the former?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to shut your window automatically when debugging stops,
"To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops."
Edit:
I forgot to mention that this is for Visual Studio 2019, Community Edition.

Comment: Calling exit at the end is irrelevant to the question and only affects return status.

Comment: I would upvote if you removed everything from your answer before the word "Again".